# Determining Regions of Rejection: Why does optional stopping affect null hypothesis testing?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, sampling

I'm having great difficulty understanding how selecting a stopping point alters the sampling space in the example below. Specifically, why is the probability of 5 successes and one failure different (3^5/4^6) when one decides to stop with an incorrect guess as compared to when one allows 6 guesses irrespective of outcome? Is it because the final guess is constrained?

[image]
source: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/statistics/#pagetopright

P.S. I do not have formal training in statistics beyond a couple research oriented stats courses and am attempting to learn more on my own. I would greatly appreciate if statistical notation or examples could be accompanied (though not replaced by) plain language. Many thanks!

Comment: I think you are looking at situation where there is a sequential rule which means the sample size is random rather than fixed.